# docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied: approving /path/to/file does not exist

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

My docker command:

```py
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/mutcompute ens_net:v3
```

Gives me the following error:

```sh
docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied: approving /Users/danny/Documents/Codes/Python/net_containers/ensemble_net: file does not exist.
```

However, I have used this same command when in the same directory for over 6 months now. It just opens my directory in the current docker container so I can run my software that is preinstalled.

Today my docker updated to version 3.0.0 (MacOS).

I am assuming this is due to the update?

I have restarted docker and I have restarted my computer. Still does not work.

Comment: In my case I had to add my projects directory to the File Sharing. The directory was there as `"/Projects"` but the project I was running it with was looking for `"/projects"` an Docker cares about that difference.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

#### [Latest EDIT] June 8, 2021

Still not fixed, note in **Docker 3.3.3** the option is no longer in Experimental features, but it's moved into `General settings`. Unchecking this still helps to resolve the issue. – [vasek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/611117/vasek)

in Docker Desktop

1. Open `Preferences`
2. Click `General`
3. Disable - `Use gRPC FUSE for file sharing`

[image]

- For a lower version, see `First Answer`.

---

#### [EDIT] January 4, 2021

It doesn't appear to have been completely fixed yet. It is recommended to just disable it.
as described in `First Answer`

---

#### [EDIT] December 18, 2020

This issue is fixed in Docker 3.0.1(macOS).

1. Open `Preferences`
2. Click `Experimental Features`
3. Disable - `Use gRPC FUSE for file sharing`
4. Update the version to ^3.0.1
5. Enable - `Use gRPC FUSE for file sharing`

---

#### First Answer

I have the same experience after updating to Docker Desktop 3.0.0(macOS).
and solved it as below.

1. Open `Preferences`
2. Click `Experimental Features`
3. Disable - `Use gRPC FUSE for file sharing`
   [image]

Comment: In my case, I had to update the version to `3.0.3` and **disable** the `Use gRPC FUSE`.

Comment: I had a similar issue when I was attempting to start Docker containers in an integration test (using the `test-containers` library) and disabling `Use gRPC FUSE` worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks  I had the similar error `approving /docker.sock: file does not exist` in version `3.1.0`. But disabling `Use gRPC FUSE for file sharing` fixed the issue.

Comment: Still not fixed, note in Docker `3.3.3` the option is no longer in Experimental features, but it's moved into `General` settings. Unchecking this still helps to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For windows: add a new folder path by clicking on + icon at
[docker screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuZvS.png)

Comment: Is there a way to do this using the docker cli?