# Why do owner and group of /var/run/docker.sock differ between host and container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am doing docker-outside-of-docker, so I mount the host's `/var/run/docker.sock` into the container via bind-mount.

Now the user and group within the container differ from the one on the host, [although they are supposed to be the same.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50325808)

```
Container:
ls -lna /var/run/docker.sock
srwxr-xr-x 1 0 0 0 Sep  2 21:30 /var/run/docker.sock
             ^- owner
               ^-group
```

```
Host:
lrwxr-xr-x  1 0  1  74  2 Sep 23:30 /var/run/docker.sock -> /Users/(...)/docker.sock
              ^- owner
                 ^-group
```

As the container is running with a non-root user, and I cannot get the groups to align, this results in a permission denied error when trying to execute docker commands.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88
```

## Solution

Via an entrypoint script, I set the needed permission on container startup.

```
chown root:docker /var/run/docker.sock
chmod g+w /var/run/docker.sock
```

It requires that the [container starts as root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47410394/1242922), and only after setting the permission changes to the jenkins user.

This solution works independent of the gRPC FUSE setting of Docker Desktop/Docker for Mac.

## Dead Ends

I gave up to solve the permission question with a bind-mount. Because:

Turns out, I overlooked that the host's `/var/run/docker.sock` is a symbolic link. I thought, due to that symbolic link, the permissions are not transferred as expected. But I could not find documentation about it, [only hints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40322275/1242922)

When bind-mounting the link target directly, when running a docker command I get

```
Error response from daemon: Mounts denied: approving /Users/(...)/docker.sock: file does not exist
```

Presumably because the file is a socket link (see `ls`' [long format](http://www.nsc.ru/cgi-bin/www/unix_help/unix-man?ls)).

Turns out, this appears to be caused by the gRPC FUSE file sharing setting of my Docker Desktop. [Disabling it made the error go away](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65246063/1242922), and the socket link `docker.sock` gets mounted with the container user as owner and group automatically.

However, exeuting e.g. `docker image ls` inside the container results in an unexplainable error now:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```